# Getting an error while assigning FK's to tables in postGIS?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints, postgis

I have created 5 tables, with four of them having a Primary Key. I then try to assign Foreign Keys using the following `alter` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE SensorLocation
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name
FOREIGN KEY (sensor_id)
REFERENCES Sensor (sensor_id)
;
ALTER TABLE DataStream
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name
FOREIGN KEY (sensorlocation_id)
REFERENCES SensorLocation (sensorlocation_id)
;
ALTER TABLE DataStream
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name
FOREIGN KEY (property_id)
REFERENCES ObservedProperty (property_id)
;
ALTER TABLE Observation
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name
FOREIGN KEY (observation_id)
REFERENCES DataStream (observation_id)
;
```

The thing is, when I only use one constraint per table, it works. But when I want to assign multiple to the table `DataStream` it doesn't work.
The error message I receive is as follows:

```
constraint "constraint_name" for relation "datastream" already exists
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this? All help is welcome!

This is our data-structure:
[image: Data-structure]

Comment: You cannot have more than one constraint with the same name (contraint_name in this case) on the same table.  Try to use different names on the constraints.

Comment: Hey @BjarniRagnarsson, I tried with a different constraint name. Now I get an error saying `ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "datastream" SQL state: 42830`

Comment: This error occurs if the column you are referencing is not unique in that table.  For instance in Sensor (sensor_id), sensor_id in the table sensor needs to be unique.  Primary keys are unique but you can define unique columns with contraints or unique index too for example.